# Is there a way to show a node's comments when displayed in teaser format on the taxonomy term page?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, nodes, comments

Is there a way to show the first page of a node's comments when the node is displayed in teaser format, e.g. on the taxonomy term page? I am building a site with 'posts' (a node type) which have comments, but I want users to be able to read comments, and leave comments from the taxonomy term page.

Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Comment: Not quite sure I get what you're trying to do here. By taxonomy pages do you mean you're looking at a set of your 'posts'?

Comment: @Malks yeah, the taxonomy term page. As in taxonomy/term/* where "*" is the tid. any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! with the help of @amateur-barista !

Here's the code I added (replace 'hook' with your module name):

```
function hook_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term' && is_numeric(arg(2))) {
      $node->content['comments'] = comment_node_page_additions($node);
  }
}
```

thanks!

david barratt

Comment: I am trying to see how this answers the question?

Comment: @JimaJamma, normally a taxonomy term page has the view_mode of 'teaser', I couldn't find a way to easily change the view_mode to 'full'. What I did instead was have Drupal build the comments with comment_node_page_additions and add this to the content array. When Drupal goes to render the taxonomy term page, the node's comments are added to the node's teaser view. (with the code above). So the code above solves my original problem I specified in the question. thanks! david barratt

Comment: @JimaJamma, to summarize: the answer above is a programatic way to add a node's comments to a taxonomy term page.

Comment: I guess what I am asking is how does this relate specifically to taxonomy pages?  To me, this just seems to create a comments section in a node's teaser view whenever and wherever it's displayed.

Comment: @JimaJamma, where else are teasers used? I guess I could include a check to see what type of page you are on.

Comment: they are used in drupal whenever a developer wants to list a set of nodes in a shorter (hence teaser) format. If you want comments displayed every time a node is displayed in both formats, the answer above is reasonable (check out hide()ing the comment LINKS in teaser format, they might be confusing now with the comments right there instead of just on a full node page) but if not, and you want comments ONLY on nodes displayed on your taxonomy pages, then yes, you should put in a check with one of arg()|$_GET['q']|request_uri() to check the path and just do it when on a taxonomy page

Comment: @JimaJamma I updated the conditional. Everything look good now? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Associate a custom node to each taxonomy term.**

1. Create a content type of "taxonomy term page" with comments enabled.
2. Add a custom field of type "taxonomy term".
3. Create a View, with a display of type block. Add to it a contextual argument of type taxonomy, and specify from where in the URL path is the argument going to be found. This should filter out nodes based on the current taxonomy found in the URL path. For safety, add a content type filter (regular, non-contextual), and specify "taxonomy term page".
4. Change the render type from "fields" to "node", or something like that. Try to see if in the node display option, you can choose to render comments as well.
5. Using Context, add a condition for `taxonomy/term/*` paths.
6. In the same Context, add a reaction of type block. Browse and select your block. Add it to the desired region. Save.
7. ...
8. Success!

I tried to suggest the "easiest" option, which was using Views. If however for some reason Views won't allow you to render a full node view - with comments enabled - then you will need to create your block programatically using hook node view. But you still get the idea. The purpose is to take advantage of the existing comment-to-node architecture to avoid writing custom code as much as possible.

Comment: yeah, I was actually looking to avoid using views because it's a high traffic site. I was looking for a more programatic way of doing it.

Comment: If you want a programmatic way then just query the database. Use pager_query() if you want to save yourself some effort. Don't be afraid of using views though.

Comment: @Malks  
yeah, I just don't see a huge advantage (other than saving some time on development), but the cost is that the performance of the site will not be as good. so I guess it really depends on the overall traffic of the site

Comment: @Malks see the answer I provided below.